# MS Report Viewer Displaying Single Page

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer2008

I'm working on a WinForms program in C# which uses a ReportViewer control to display a fairly large `*.rdlc` report. The report was recently upgraded to the 2008 version, and now displays what should be **80+ pages as a single page** and cuts off the bottom. It only seems to happen on one specific report, though it works fine in print preview and exports to PDF OK.

It may be that the report is just too long?

The only thing I've come across on Google suggested making all the cell `KeepTogether` properties true, which didn't help.

Comment: I ended up just programatically opening the report in print preview as a workaround

Comment: You can post your comment as answer and accept it so that future readers will find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Open Your .rdlc file

```
goto Report-->ReportProperties-->Layout
```

Adjust your height,width,top,bottom